# Exercise 2. 3. 8 from Tao-Vu's Additive Combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics, additive-combinatorics

**Problem:** Let $A$ be an additive set in an additive group $Z$ and let $G$ be a finite subgroup of $Z$. Show that $$\sigma[A + G] \leq \frac{|3A|}{|A|}.$$ Conclude that if $\pi: Z \to Z'$
is a group homomorphism then $$\sigma[\pi(A)] \leq \frac{|3A|}{|A|}.$$
The notation used is $\sigma[A] = \frac{|A+A|}{|A|}$ for an additive set $A$.
The first part is easy but I cant find the solution to the second part of the problem.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hint: By the First Isomorphism theorem, the image $\pi(Z)$ is isomorphic to $Z/\ker(\pi)$.

Comment: @ThomasBloom Unfortunately I don't see how this would help, since it's not a given that the homomorphism in the problem has a finite kernel.

Comment: Good point, I was thinking about finite groups. I don't see how to recover the full statement via the exercise, but it's simple enough to prove directly: for each $z\in \pi(A)+\pi(A)$, choose some $a_z,b_z$ such that $\pi(a_z)+\pi(b_z)=z$. Then the map $(z,c)\mapsto (a_z+b_z+c,\pi(c))$ is an injection from $(\pi(A)+\pi(A))\times A\to  3A\times \pi(A)$.

Comment: (In fact this simple argument shows the more general inequality $\lvert \pi(B)\rvert/\lvert \pi(A)\rvert \leq \lvert A+B\rvert/\lvert A\rvert$ for any $A,B$.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. +1

Comment: @ThomasBloom, nice answer! I remember I had an issue with that problem. https://mathoverflow.net/questions/412208/doubling-constant-of-homomorphic-image-of-additive-set-is-leq-dfrac3aa

Comment: @ThomasBloom Great answer.  It's helpful if answers are posted as answers rather than just comments.

Answer (score 1):

The latter inequality can be proved directly, using the idea from the proof of the Ruzsa triangle inequality. In fact we can prove the more general fact

$$ \frac{\lvert \pi(B)\rvert}{\lvert \pi(A)\rvert}\leq \frac{\lvert A+B\rvert}{\lvert A\rvert},$$

(and then set $B=A+A$ to recover the desired inequality). To prove this, for any $z\in \pi(B)$, choose some $b_z$ arbitrarily such that $\pi(b_z)=z$. Then the map

$$ (z,a) \mapsto (a+b_z, \pi(a))$$

is easily checked to be an injection from $\pi(B)\times A \to (A+B)\times \pi(A)$.